# ! Paragraph ended before \@lbibitem was complete

Tags: apacite

I am working with apacite bibliography style. I am getting one single error as mentioned above. I have not used any bibitem. When compiling the bibtex file I am getting many warnings related to the urls- "no author, editor, title, type, and howpublished ". Something like this. I have provided the urls and lastchecked fields. Other similar url references are not giving any warning. The location of the file causing error has no \cite{..}.

The packages I have used are specified as follows:

```
\documentclass[]{interact}

\usepackage{epstopdf}% To incorporate .eps illustrations using PDFLaTeX, etc.
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{\urlstyle{APACsame}}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,sort&compress]{natbib}% Citation support using natbib.sty
\bibpunct[, ]{(}{)}{;}{a}{,}{,}% Citation support using natbib.sty
```

After this `\begin{document}` is kept.

```
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{mybibfile1}
```

are kept before `\end{document}`

One sample url giving warning is specified in the following way:

```
@misc{refer26,
url={https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/}, lastchecked = {17.01.2020}}
```

Please help me.

Comment: Note that if you want `natbib` commands with `apacite`, you should load `apacite` as `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}` (and *not* load `natbib` manually). I can not reproduce the `! Paragraph ended before \@lbibitem was complete` error from the code shown so far (an MWE would be more useful: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), but the entry `refer26` is simply  too sparse for `apacite`, you should try to at least add a name and a year.

Comment: If the URL in `refer26` is the real deal and not just a placeholder, then the following entry might be more to `apacite`'s liking `@misc{refer26,
  author = {{U.S. National Library of Medicine}},
  title = {Unified Medical Language System {(UMLS)}},
  year = {2019},
  url={https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/},
  lastchecked = {17.01.2020}}`

Comment: There is a note at the bottom of https://www.nlm.nih.gov/research/umls/index.html suggesting to cite the following entry when one uses the UMLS: `@article{umls,
  author = {Olivier Bodenreider},
  title  = {{The Unified Medical Language System (UMLS)}: Integrating Biomedical Terminology},
  journal = {Nucleic Acids Res.},
  year  = {2004},
  volume = {32},
  number = {S1},
  pages = {D267--D270},
  doi = {10.1093/nar/gkh061},
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, The problem has been solved by rectifying the urls following the advise.